# Why the results of decimal operation is incorrect?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, decimal

I want to use as a double value to 2 decimal places. But I think I got Incorrect value.

1.965 = must be 1.97 but result is 1.96

I tired them:

`DecimalFormat("0.00")` or `DecimalFormat("#.##")` or `NumberFormat.getInstance() / ..setMaximumFractionDigits(2)`

but the result has not changed.

Thanks..

```
    Log.e("Result:", String.format("%.2f", 1.965 )); // 1.96  < ?
    Log.e("Result:", String.format("%.2f", 1.975 )); // 1.98
    Log.e("Result:", String.format("%.2f", 1.955 )); // 1.96
    Log.e("Result:", String.format("%.2f", 1.9650 )); // 1.96 < ?
    Log.e("Result:", String.format("%.2f", 1.9651 )); // 1.97
    Log.e("Result:", String.format("%.2f", 1.966 )); // 1.97
```

Comment: You might want to add a language tag.

Comment: I don't get the same results: https://ideone.com/vzrOmn Please give us more details like jdk version, locale, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is in the way that floating point numbers are repesented internally. They are of the form (binary mantissa) * 2^(binary exponent). Usually, any decimal number cannot be represented *exactly* in binary form, so some rounding takes place already when calculating that representation.

In a nutshell, your number 1.965 is likely to end up represented as a binary floating point number that is a tiny bit less than 1.965, and when your program rounds it to 2 decimal places, you get this kind of unexpected result.

Here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html is a comprehensive overview of the pitfalls of floating point arithmetic.

Comment: The odd thing here is that assuming IEEE 754 binary64 doubles and round-to-nearest rounding mode, `1.965` should actually be stored as `1.9650000000000000799360577730112709105014801025390625`, so should round up.  This sounds like a sloppy `format` implementation to me.

Comment: Ah, we're on android.  That might explain why there are shortcuts leading to either non-correctly-rounded string-to-double conversion (in converting the literal to a double) or non-correctly-rounded double-to-string conversion (in the formatting operation).